# Unable to alter the column using DDL in Spanner, postgres flavor, to set the not-null constraint

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-spanner

I am executing this query:

```
ALTER TABLE projects ALTER COLUMN quota bigint NOT NULL;
```

Error:

```
Statement failed: [ERROR] syntax error at or near "bigint"; failed to parse the DDL statements.
```

I also tried:

```
ALTER TABLE projects ALTER COLUMN quota set NOT NULL;
```

and in that, the error was:

```
Statement failed: <SET/DROP NOT NULL> are allowed only after <ALTER COLUMN> action of <ALTER TABLE> statement.
```

I followed the official documentation but still not able to see how the query is wrong:

Documentation for describing the alteration is [here](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/reference/postgresql/data-definition-language).
Example is [here](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/schema-updates).

This is an excerpt from the official documentation itself:

```
ALTER TABLE Songwriters ALTER COLUMN Nickname STRING(MAX) NOT NULL;
```

How to set not null for a column?

Answer (score 1):

Modifying an existing column requires that the `ALTER TABLE` statement contains two `ALTER COLUMN` clauses. The first `ALTER COLUMN` clause must specify the data type, and the second `ALTER COLUMN`  clause must specify the nullability.

So in your case the statement must be:

```
ALTER TABLE projects
  ALTER COLUMN quota type bigint,
  ALTER COLUMN quota SET NOT NULL;
```

This requirement is a specific requirement for Cloud Spanner PostgreSQL, and a deviation from open-source PostgreSQL (see the 'Spanner differences from open-source PostgreSQL section'): https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/reference/postgresql/data-definition-language#alter_table